# what is the meaning of "untelegraphed" and "98% mark" here?

Tags: word-usage

Of the remaining three reveals, one was entirely tangential and inconsequential to the story, completely untelegraphed, happens around the 98% mark, and left me with a “Huh. Well… that’s nice, I suppose.” reaction.

from https://mattgemmell.com/review-origin-by-dan-brown/

Comment: [Telegraph (verb)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telegraph) : 2 : to make known by signs especially unknowingly and in advance

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *untelegraphed* here means that the subject reveal was not given away before the reveal. Merriam-Webster provides this definition of the transitive verb *telegraph*:"to make known by signs especially unknowingly and in advance." (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/telegraphed).

The phrase *98% mark* indicates that the reveal happened 98% of the way through the story, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

The review is very condensed.  90% and 98% describe the position in the book as an alternative to page numbers.

'Untelegraphed' is related to the meaning [2] in Merriam-Webster, already cited. It is clear 'mattgemmell' is describing a fault in the writing from an author's point of view. In this case it is a failure to set the scene; a failure to create a believable setting for the reveal; and his failure to give any hints about this character/ happening. 'The third reveal,' cheats the reader. Dan Brown likes magic; but no-one would take him seriously if a boy wizard popped up, totally untelegraphed, and sorted everything. This reviewer  thinks the reveal is the wrong sort of surprise.